# Are declarative pipeline environment variables are shared across different stages?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Is it expected that environmental variables can be accessed from different stages of a declarative pipeline?

Here is my code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('start') {
            environment {
               tool="alpha"
            }
            steps {
                script {
                   tool="beta"
                   echo tool
                }
            }
        }
        stage('end') {
            steps {
                echo tool
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

both echo are printing "beta"

So is it expected that tool variable declared in `stage('start')` are accessible in `stage('end')` too?

Comment: Interesting - you'd expect for the environment variable to be scoped to the 'start' stage and not be set in the 'end' stage. Whether this is a bug or not, I think it's best to set the environment variable at the pipeline level if you want to use it across multiple stages - both for clarity and for future-proofing (in case this is indeed a bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo tool` doesn't print `tool` environment variable, it print a Groovy variable. And you set it to `"beta"` without defining it first, which Jenkins magically transformed into a global Groovy (not environment) variable for you.

Try with

```
sh script: 'echo $tool'
```

or

```
echo env.tool
```

to test what the environment variables do.